# I need help adjusting an algorithm with a list of package deliveries to find the shortest path

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, nearest-neighbor

I'm working on a giant project for Data Structures & Algorithms that will take a list of packages with special notes and organize them onto 3 trucks, find the shortest delivery route, and deliver them.

I have already optimized the data by using Dijkstra's to create a dictionary that contains the shortest distance between two locations, represented by location IDs.

The part I am working on now to create an algorithm that will take a list of location IDs for a truck, and starting at the hub ID, find the nearest neighbor. Then I need to start at the nearest neighbor and find the next hub, and continue until I have delivered all packages, then go back to the hub.  I need to save this order and total milage.

I have erased and rewritten so many times and I feel like I am close but I'm having some trouble narrowing it down and I am hoping for guidance on what I'm missing.

I don't want to include too much code so just a quick overview; 
Locations is a list that contains 16 location IDs, some of them duplicates.

```
# This is to set the initial location to the hub, where all trucks 
start. 
current = hubID 
path = []
totalMileage = 0

def findPath(locations):
    tempList = []

    for i in locations:
        # d.dijkstraSearch(fromid, toid) returns an optimized 
        distance in miles 
        dist = d.dijkstraSearch(current, i)
        tempList.append([dist], [i])

    tempList.sort()
    min = tempList[0]
    current = closest location?
    total mileage += distance of closest location?
    locations.remove(location ID of closest location)
    findPath(locations)

findPath(locations)
```

My goal is to find the shortest distance from the current location, then add that distance to the total milage and closest location to the path. However, right now I'm not sure how to access tempList individually so that I can add each corresponding index to the correct list/total. I also then need to change the current variable to the closest location, than recursively call it again so that I get all the way to the end of the list, then go back to the hub. I think I'm dealing with the two dimensional arrays incorrectly, and not looping through the list appropriately, but I can't pinpoint the way to fix it. Any suggestions or observations about where to go next would be great thank you!

Comment: Is this traveling salesman? Except with three salesmen (delivery trucks)?

Comment: This segment of the project is essentially that, yes! Ideally I'm trying to create the algorithm to only worry about one truck, and then I'll just call it on each truck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need that keeping track of everything and sorting business when you are just looking for the minimum.

Otherwise, you are indeed really close to something that works, for example this:

```
current = hubID 
path = []
totalMileage = 0

def findPath(locations):
  # We need to tell Python that this is defined in the global scope
  global current, totalMileage

  # Make sure you always have a base case when defining a recursive function!
  # We don't want to recurse for ever.
  if len(locations) == 0: 
    return

  # We will keep track of the closest location encountered and its distance
  closest_location = -1
  closest_location_dist = float("inf")

  # We need to update the closest location if we see a closer one
  for i in locations:
    dist = d.dijkstraSearch(current, i)
    if dist < closest_location_dist:
      closest_location = i
      closest_location_dist = dist

  current = closest_location
  path.append(current)
  totalMileage += closest_location_dist
  locations.remove(closest_location)
  findPath(locations)

findPath(locations)
```

Beware to not include the hub in the locations (otherwise the hub will be the closest neighbour to itself) and that this will not include travelling back to the hub. Also the starting node is not listed in "path" (I left this as is, I don't know if it was a choice). And finally, know that the "locations" list will be empty after having called the function, so you will need to make/pass a copy if you still need it afterwards.

Even though it works, it is generally bad practice to have your functions rely on global variables to get the job done (it can lead to name collisions and get very messy). The following might be a bit better:

```
def findPath(locations, current):
  if len(locations) == 0: 
    return [], 0

  closest_location = -1
  closest_location_dist = float("inf")

  for i in locations:
    dist = d.dijkstraSearch(current, i)
    if dist < closest_location_dist:
      closest_location = i
      closest_location_dist = dist

  current = closest_location
  locations.remove(current)
  path_todo, mileage_todo = findPath(locations, current)

  path = [current] + path_todo
  totalMileage = closest_location_dist + mileage_todo

  return path, totalMileage

path, totalMileage = findPath(locations, hubID)
```

(with the same warnings as previously)

Last but not least, this algorithm will not always give the best possible path. It might even lead to the *worst* possible path in some edge-cases. It might still be enough for what you want to do. The best possible path is probably impossible to always compute in "reasonable" time as the [Travelling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) is [NP-Hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NP-hardness), but there exists algorithms which guarantee to be somewhat close to the best tour in a well behaved graph, such as the [Christofides algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christofides_algorithm) for metric distances.

Comment: So sorry for the late response, but thanks so much for your detailed explanation!!

Comment: So if I wanted to include the 'back to the hub' distance in the algorithm, I was thinking about how I could do that. Would I create another base case, if len(locations) == 1, and then instead of return say totalMileage += d.dijkstrasearch(locations[0], hubID), or is that on the right track?

Comment: You're on the right track, but you should use the "len(locations) == 0" base case and do totalMileage += d.dijkstrasearch(current, hubID) before the return. (or in my variation of the code, you would "return [], d.dijkstrasearch(current, hubID)" instead of "return [], 0").

Comment: -- don't forget to accept the answer if you are satisfied with it :) --

Comment: Thank you so much!! Your explanation helped a lot, I really understand it better now. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: So sorry, but I just have one more question. I have modified the algorithm to be more general for three separate trucks. Before the algorithm, I create  mileageOne(for truck one), mileageTwo(for truck two), and mileageThree(for truck three) and set each equal to zero. Then in the algorithm instead of taking only locations, I take locations, path, and mileage. When I call each on each truck, I say findPath(locationsOne, pathOne, mileageOne). It works great for each truck, except then when I try to set up totalMileage = mileageOne + mileageTwo + mileageThree, it says 0. Am I missing a reference?

Comment: If I understand what you say correctly, it might be a case of confusing variables in the global and local scopes (that's what happens when you try to use global variables everywhere :p). My advise is not to do that and maybe to take inspiration of the second piece of code in my answer. Then you can just do "mileageX = findPath(locationsX, hubID)" for each truck before summing everything up. Notice that my function defines everything it needs to work inside the function (or gets it through the function arguments). That's generally what you want.